# Getting "FacebookLoginStatus.error" when i log in with facebook flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0, flutter-facebook-login

my code for log in facebook with flutter firebase not working. and will get the case of case FacebookLoginStatus.error:

```
bool loading = false;
UserInfo user;
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
static final FacebookLogin _facebookSignIn = new FacebookLogin();
Future _loginfb() async {
FacebookLoginResult result = await _facebookSignIn.logIn(['email']);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    await _loginWithFb(result);
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    setState(() => loading = false);
    print("bb");
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    setState(() => loading = false);
    print(FacebookLoginStatus.error.index.toString() + " eee");
    break;
}
}
Future _loginWithFb(FacebookLoginResult _result) async {
FacebookAccessToken _accessToken = _result.accessToken;
AuthCredential _credential =
    FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: _accessToken.token);
var a = await _auth.signInWithCredential(_credential);
setState(() {
  loading = true;
  user = a.user;
});
}
```

package imported

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

the full console error logs:
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): notify runnable to start.
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1770):   HWUI Binary is  enabled

```
I/HwPhoneWindow( 1770): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor( 1770): enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector( 1770): onAttached, package=com.lazaarworks.TimyTimeMain, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
W/InputMethodManager( 1770): startInputReason = 1
    D/mali_winsys( 1770): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/ViewRootImpl( 1770): jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): stop checker.
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): Current Activity:false
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): not watching, wait.
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): notify runnable to start.
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): restart watching
    W/InputMethodManager( 1770): startInputReason = 1
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): stop checker.
    W/InputMethodManager( 1770): startInputReason = 1
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 1770): notify runnable to start.
    D/ViewRootImpl[FacebookActivity]( 1770): surface should not be released
    D/ActivityThread( 1770): Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{d90a276 token=android.os.BinderProxy@edbcbab {com.lazaarworks.TimyTimeMain/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@edbcbab
    W/libEGL  ( 1770): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7efc4dd010 disconnect failed
    I/flutter ( 1770): FacebookLoginStatus.error
    I/flutter ( 1770): eee
```

Comment: Please give error logs.

Comment: in the switch will get the last case (case FacebookLoginStatus.error:)

Comment: Can you print the error? It can be seen in debug console.

Comment: D/ViewRootImpl[FacebookActivity]( 1770): surface should not be released
D/ActivityThread( 1770): Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{d004042 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d4c1ec7 {com.lazaarworks.TimyTimeMain/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@d4c1ec7
W/libEGL  ( 1770): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7efc382010 disconnect failed
I/flutter ( 1770): FacebookLoginStatus.error

Comment: Paste the full console error logs in your post.

Comment: console posted.

Comment: I checked this package. It not really active. Maybe try another one. https://pub.dev/packages?q=facebook+login